# Virtualmin cannot connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, error, webmin, centos

I have a VPS running Webmin/Virtualmin. I host multiple domains, one of which is a Drupal 7 website that uses a MySQL database. Yesterday I went to 'Manage' the database and found that I recieved the following error `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` and that I can't access it in anyway. I wondered whether it was because my version of MySQL was out of date (it is 5.1.17) so before updated, I tried to back up the database by going to Webmin >> Servers >> MySQL Database Server >> Backup Databases - only to receive the following page:

> Database backup failed : mysqldump failed :
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during
>   query when using LOCK TABLES Database backup failed : mysqldump failed
>   :
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) when trying to
>   connect Database backup failed : mysqldump failed :
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
>   Successfully backed up 1348 bytes from database test to file
>   /home/test.sql.
>
> Scheduled backup for database left disabled.

I have set 'Allow big tables?' to Yes and the maximum packet size to 5 MB in the MySQL Server Configuration but I still receive the errors. The file size of the database is only 156 MB, it has 190 tables and it is likely to hold much more data than it does now.

Does anyone have any advice? I'm running CentOS.

**UPDATE:** Since posting this question, I have been in contact with my hosting company who advised be to upgrade MySQL. I'm now running version 5.5.38 and have exactly the same problem. I installed the latest version of phpMyAdmin and have some strange behaviour. When I try to view the database, it says that the session has timed out but when I log back in no databases appear and I'm told that there are no tables in the database I just clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these resources that may help. They explain the errors rather well and what to do about them.

Got error: 2013: Lost connection...

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query
- https://serverfault.com/questions/29597/what-does-mysql-error-2013-mean
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html

Got error: 2002: Can't connect to...

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46296/mysql-works-mysqldump-doesnt

It sounds like these are fairly simple configuration issues. I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply and thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I'm still stuck with the 2013 error. LOCK TABLES seems to be a big clue as that is where the error comes from, but I'm not entirely sure what it means. I've even submitted a support ticket with my hosting company but they appear to be stuck for ideas.

Comment: Sometimes when no-one has offered an answer, I try and do some research and offer something. I feel like people should get an answer as much as possible. If I can come across something new/different, then I will post again.

Comment: Thank you that is much appreciated. I feel the same way. Soon, I am going to update my question to include my progress.

Comment: Anytime! I like helping people. I will tightening up my answer for future users later today. You may want to see if you can delete the comment with your domain name now that things are fixed.

Comment: Same, it keeps me going. I don't really mind my domain name being on show for now, and besides - things are far from fixed unfortunately.

Comment: Oooopppsss! I momentarily lost my mind. I was thinking of another user with my last comment. I am getting old! I do like helping people. Especially webmasters. I like them and I have no idea why. Probably because I R 1!? I am searching for another answer for you.

Comment: @Andy Here is something you can do for now if it is possible. If you have another computer capable of running MySQL, you can install the same version (or very close to it) of MySQL on that computer, stop your problem server, copy the data files from the problem server to the new server, start the problem server, and point the new server to your data files and restart the new server. Your database should appear on the new server. This is at least a work around for now.

Comment: I am not sure if you have checked/repaired your tables lately. Generally, you should not need to do this, but I am seeing this error associated with table issues. Here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582832/repair-all-tables-in-one-go I would suggest proceeding with some caution though MySQL is very good at inspecting and repairing tables. You can also check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html Something to think about.

Comment: I apologise for not replying. I did read your comments and ultimately they did help this morning, but I was getting so stressed and I figured it would be best to leave it to the technicians at my hosting company seeing as though I had submitted a support ticket. They got me half way there - apparently my VPS was in a right state. Somehow my PHP binaries were not installed correctly, so we updated PHP and MySQL and got phpMyAdmin - only to discover the database was pretty corrupt. They manually repaired the database for me, but I still had some strange behaviour.

Comment: When I tried to look at the database structure, phpMyAdmin said there were no tables but yet I could see the tables in the tree view in the left sidebar and browse them individually. So I ran `mysql_check` to find that it was getting stuck at the same table each time... In phpMyAdmin I exported these tables (just in case) and dropped them one by one. As soon as I dropped the last dodgy table, the structure was available again and everything is back to normal. Minus those tables, that belonged to a Drupal 7 Module called webforms... this shocked me.

Comment: @Andy MySQL is extremely stable from my experience. I cannot even imagine what happened in your case. It must have been rather odd. I am just glad you got is straight! Congrats!! BTW- for the first time ever, I had a MySQL problem last night- a orphaned lock on a table/row. Just had to restart MySQL. It only took a decade to get an error!

Comment: Thanks, I really don't know what went on here because like you, I haven't really had any problems with MySQL so for something as major as this to happen, and to be indirectly caused by Drupal, really shocked me. Although, as you know, I don't have that much experience. To make things even more freaky, I re-imported those tables that caused all the issues after I was able to create a backup with absolutely no issues whatsoever. Definately appears to have been some kind of index issue.